# DO Spaces [or S3] + Nginx with subdomain

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, digital-ocean

All, i'm running into issues proxying a subdomain to a DO space (suspect that AWS/S3 would act the same way); in this case, trying to serve logos off the bucket, with the requested url being `logos.mysite.com/dev/logo1`. Nginx should proxy_pass this to https://mybucket.dospace.com/logos/dev/logo1.png (and it will always be .png).

NGINX setup is currently:

```
server{
    server_name logos.mysite.com
    location / {
        set $bucket "mybucket.dospace.com"
        proxy_pass https://$bucket/logos$request_uri.png;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        ... other proxy_set/hide settings ...
    }
```

Above is simplest version of many rewrite/return/regex location attempts, but nothing works. In the example above (using chrome), a redirect to `https://mybucket.dospace.com/dev/logo1.png` occurs, which is missing `/logos` in the path. Moreover, I don't want chrome to redirect at all - it's more convenient for the user to see the original request from `logos.mysite.com` (if that's possible).

Was anyone able to execute on a similar setup?

Comment: Doesn't seting a variable $logos as "/logos" work? I mean, if bucket is there right, another variable for logos should work. I'm out of my computer rn and this is the first thing I'd try. If it doesn't work I'll get back later with what I found.

Comment: @flaixman, nope, doesn't really work, same issue even if `set $logos "/logos";` is introduced.